# ionic cordova add android error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

Following error is generating while running this command,unable to build apk.

```
$ ionic cordova platform add android
```

> cordova platform add android --save
>   Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0
>
> Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.3.0
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Ionic info cli packages: (C:\Users\Sahil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.2
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.9.0
    npm  : 5.5.1
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files\Android1\Android Studio\bin

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: Are you running the command on the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix -

DELETE the downloaded file cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz or folder npm-304 8-83f48a6f under-
C:\Users**{userName}**\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-304 8-83f48a6f\registry.npmjs.org\cordova-android-\cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz

And do cordova platform add android again. npm will redownload the required file.
You can also download it manually (7.7 MB) from here and place it in the same folder and then run the command.

or delete all the files in the temp folder add the downloaded file in the root folder of
C:\Users**{userName}**\AppData\Local\Temp\cordova-android-6.2.3.tgz

Worked For Me

Comment: Could you specify the android version which you are using.
Say, if your using 6.0.0, then ionic platform add android@6.0.0

Comment: I down graded the CLI version , and then added the cordova Now the apk is builiding ....

but in the it is showing error  after builiding apk .

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 9.675 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).

Answer (score 0):

i was try this and fix this problem ...
     remove cordova and then install cordova using

```
 npm install -g cordova
```

if this not work then remove nodemodules and install nodemodules using

```
 npm install
```